# Manipulate Html form before POSTing

Tags: php, html, forms

Basically, I have a normal html form where the user is required to enter a few details (buy.php), I then POST that further to a merchant's gateway `action="http://.."`

Now, how can I manipulate the details the user has just entered before posting them to the merchant?

i.e. the user chooses to buy a shirt ($15.00), how can I ADD a standard shipping fee of say ($10.00),
and post them together in a "total-amount" field to the "http://.."?

Even better, Can I turn the info the user just entered into PHP variables, to perform further manipulations.. like combine them and md5 them..etc (all within buy.php)?

Thanks your help is very appreciated

Comment: There are a few approaches.  You can use JavaScript to manipulate values all you like, though keep in mind that any client-side code can be modified and users can manipulate values themselves.  (That is, if the user is telling the merchant how much items should cost, that's likely a bit of a problem.)  Conversely, you can post the form to your own server-side code and then from server-side code you can communicate with the merchant.  That way you can perform all of the logic and validation you like in PHP and the user never communicates directly with the merchant.

Comment: Technically, if the user has entered the values into a form that posts data to your PHP page, they're already PHP variables found in `$_POST`.

Comment: @David, Thanks, I understand what you mean, I would go with the latter option, I can create a php script to receive the initial data & manipulate them, I just don't know how to make it **automatically** POST them further. This problem wouldn't exist if for example I prompted the user (using the 2nd script) to press a confirm button or something, you get what I mean?

Comment: Thinking more about what you're saying I must ask, are you actually taking a dollar amount from the page the user sees, and using that amount?

Comment: In other words, is there a field on the page that looks like this `<input name="totalBox" type="text" readonly>` or something similar, that you're actually using to POST an amount from?

Comment: You'r asking if I'm literally taking a value of "$xx.xx", the answer would be no, APIs use values like "USD, GBP" to handle currencies.

Comment: Let me rephrase. Currently, when the values are being passed to the merchant via POST data, where does the data get submitted from?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the wording of your question, but it sounds like you may be about do something which could turn into a security nightmare for you.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger Hi, the data get submitted from a normal html form. I **do** have an amount box where the user can enter their amount (name your price thing). -  I should say nevertheless that issue has been resolved, thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dunno which merchant gateway you are using, but there is always optional (HTML) parameters are provided by merchant in order to charge customer for extra fees like shipping charges, initial setup fee, tax etc.

If you want to update/edit form data, before you post it to merchant's gateway url

You can implement one of other following logic:

1) mentioned the extra fee which you are charging to your customer
and using javascript add it to the product price and show the total
please follow the comments if merchants api provide js api with encryption then go for first option (ref: https://wiki.foxycart.com/v/0.7.0/advanced/json)
Other wise it is bad idea because of security issue
I suggested option because I have implemented foxycart api in that way

2) You can use curl post to post data to the merchant's url
   first post data to your file like buy.php ----> checkout.php
   on checkout do your calculation and update the required param then using curl post it to merchant's gateway url

Point 2) seems better for more security but please note before you charge extra fees you must need to show on view/html (hidden charges always make bad impression)

Comment: Using client side code to manipulate a price that a person is actually going to be charged is a horrible idea. What happens if I pull up my JavaScript console in my browser and call the function with my own values, like a negative value for instance?

Comment: @LeonNewswanger you are right.. updating the answer, I suggested this because I have implemented foxycart using js api but it is token based and also use html parameter encryption

Comment: Thankyou, I tried to avoid having a second server-side script where the user would have to press "confirm" (well, to post the manipulated data as hidden fields). I guess there's no easy way around it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options:

1-use onSubmit event in form. define a function that recieve form data, manipulate and finally execute form.submit();

2-send data without manipulate to buy.php and perform manipulations with php.

I recommend second option for security reasons. If you use javascript any user seeing source code of your page could see your fees and others confidentials data.